# Given a latitude, longitude and heading, how can I determine the lat/lon that is x meters from that point?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have a series of lat/lon which represents the center of some object.  I need to draw a line through this point that is x meters on either side of the center *and* it needs to be perpendicular to the heading (imagine a capital `T`)

Ultimately I want to get the lat/lon of this line's endpoints.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic calculation is in this similar question's answer: [Calculate second point knowing the starting point and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187657/). Calculate the points for the two headings perpendicular to the main heading the distance away you want.

Comment: @Brain: Can you fix that link please?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: [Core Location extensions for bearing and distance](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=120)

With those extensions and  two points on the initial line you should be able to get the bearing, add/subtract pi/2 and find points to either side like this:

```
double bearing = [bottomOfT bearingInRadiansTowardsLocation:topOfT];
CLLocation *left = [topOfT newLocationAtDistance:meters
                             alongBearingradians:bearing+M_PI/2];
CLLocation *right = [topOfT newLocationAtDistance:meters
                              alongBearingradians:bearing-M_PI/2];
```