# Get Latitude Longitude based on Distance and Degree

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location, latitude-longitude

I need to get the lat-long on basis of current lat-long, distance and degree.

What I want to know is,

> If my current lat-long is, for example, 40.7142, 74.0064
>   And I have
>   distance, say, 10 miles
>   And I have degree, say, 40 degree clockwise from north

Now basis of above data I need to calculate the another lat-long for that point.

How to calculate the lat-long on basis of distance and degree ?

Thanks ...

Comment: What line is the angle measured from?  Is it degrees clockwise from north?

Comment: [Here is exactly what you're looking for](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) (plus a ton of fascinating information on the subject). More specifically look into _Destination point given distance and bearing from start point_ paragraph. It also have examples written in Javascript so you can easily implement them in Obj-C.

Comment: Possible duplicate to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187657/calculate-second-point-knowing-the-starting-point-and-distance

Comment: Also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6634982/467105).