# calculate point given bearing, length and starting point

Tags: math, 2d, trigonometry

I'm working on a 2d (x,y) plane. I have the initial point, a length and a bearing relative to north-aviation style bearing. Can someone help me calculate the end point of this line? I've seen a few different formulas but my maths isn't great so I'm not sure if they are correct.

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic: this isn't a programming question...

Comment: It might not be a 'programming' question but once I know how to solve this I will adding the code/converting the formula to code to my application. I've seen similar questions which received answers and weren't denounced as off-topic.

Comment: Sure.  But the most appropriate thing to do would be to pick up an introductory maths book that covers trigonometry and geometry.  Because my guess would be that this isn't going to be the only trig problem you encounter...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate second point knowing the starting point and distance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187657/calculate-second-point-knowing-the-starting-point-and-distance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[image: Sketch]

where `r` is the distance and `t` the angle (in radians). Note the `+y` is towards `North`.

Comment: That should be a plus sign in the formula for x_B if positive x points east, as it should in a right handed coordinate system.

Comment: Oh yes, the positive angle is CW and not CCW. Fixed.

Comment: No, in a right handed coordinate system the angle is zero at the x-axis and is positive in the CCW direction.  Your coordinate system is left handed if CW is positive.

Comment: I added a picture which should explain my choice of signs.

Comment: I think the second equation is incorrect; the sign should be negative; -r*cos(t).  The convention that I gave you is the most common one.  Make t = 0 at the x-axis and your life will be much, much better.